# How to make this contacts page faster?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, contacts, android-contacts

I'm wondering why my code takes so long to open. It takes a good 2-4 seconds on my android device (LG G4) in order to open this fragment. I have a phone contact class with these variables I want to retrieve in them.

```
    public class PhoneContact {
    public String contact_name = "";
    public String contact_number = "";
    public int contact_id = 0;
}
```

In order to inflate these contacts I have a listview fragment that displays these data. I display the fragment by doing this:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle SavedInstanceState){
    myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_phonecontacts, container, false);
    getPhoneContact();
    return myFragmentView;
}
```

Finally in order to retrieve my phone contacts information I did this:

```
public void getPhoneContact() {
    ArrayList<PhoneContact> phoneContacts = new ArrayList<PhoneContact>();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    try {
        cursor = contentResolver.query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error on contact list", e.getMessage());
    }

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) { 
            PhoneContact phoneContact = new PhoneContact();
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phoneContact.contact_name = name;

            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                        , null
                        , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                        , new String[]{id}
                        , null);

                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()){
                    String number = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    phoneContact.contact_number = number;
                }
                phoneCursor.close();
            }
            phoneContacts.add(phoneContact);
        }
        PhoneContactsAdapter adapter = new PhoneContactsAdapter(this.getContext(), phoneContacts);
        ListView listView = (ListView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.listview_phoneContacts);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Checked if the cursor is able to traverse through the contact database.
If it is then go through each contact and grab their ID, name, phone number.
Once there are no more contacts to search for I close the cursor and then make the phone contact. The home contact gets added to the array and then binds to the list view through an adapter.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed this up or another way to retrieve my phone contacts.

Comment: Load the contacts on app opening instead on the screen, use a recyclerview, and reduce the multiple iterations (while/for).

Comment: @jturolla any suggestions on how to reduce iteration through contacts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do getPhoneContact in AsyncTask, then you can post the result via [publishPorgress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)) to have nice UX. One more, using RecyclerView with [notifyItemInserted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int)) instead of ListView will have nice animation when add contact view to list

Answer (score 0):

So you currently have a query per contact on the device (assuming most if not all contact contain phone numbers).

Instead, you can get the same date in a single query - all the data about contacts is actually stored in a single table `Data`, which supports an **implicit join** with the Contacts table.

```
Map<Long, PhoneContact> contacts = new HashMap<Long, PhoneContact>();

String[] projection = {Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER};
// you can add more mimetypes here if you need more info, e.g. emails
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')"; 
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String number = cur.getString(2);

    // only add to the hashmap if this is a newly found contact
    if (!contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        PhoneContact phoneContact = new PhoneContact();
        phoneContact.contact_id = id;
        phoneContact.contact_name = name;
        phoneContact.contact_number = number;
        contacts.put(id, phoneContact);
    }
}
cur.close();

// You'll now have all info in `contacts`, you can get a list of just the values via `contacts.values()`
```

By the way, your `PhoneContact` class doesn't seem to support multiple phones per contact, you can change your class to have a `List<String> phones;` instead of that single String, and then modify the above code a bit to support adding multiple phones.